# Realizar acción únicamente antes de cerrar una pestaña en JavaScript (no cuando se recargue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

El evento beforeunload se dispara cuando recargo o cierro una pestaña; sin embargo necesito realizar una acción únicamente cuando se cierra, no cuando se recarga. En este caso, necesito decrementar una variable:

```
// Incrementar la variable cuando se abra una nueva pestaña
$(window).on("load", function(event)
{
    // La página NO ha sido recargada
    if (performance.navigation.type != 0)
    {
        variable += 1;
    }
});

// Decrementar la variable cuando se cierre una pestaña
$(window).on("beforeunload", function(event)
{
    variable -= 1;
});
```

La variable se decrementa también cuando recargo la página.

Answer (score 0):

De momento no se puede obtener la información del evento si se trata de recargar la pagina o de cerrar la pestaña del navegador, te recomendaría busques la forma de hacer lo mismo con el evento `onload` y a lo mejor usando la diferencia entre el tiempo entre `unload` y `onload` sepas si recargo o cerro, si fue recarga debería durar un par de segundos y si cierra demora más, podríamos marcar un parámetro de que si la ultima vez y en el momento que estas abriendo duro menos de 3 segundos es porque recargo la pagina

```
window.onload = function(){
  var lastTime = localStorage.getItem('lastTime')
  if(lastTime){
    lastTime = Number(lastTime)
    var now = new Date().getMilliseconds()
    var difference = (now - lastTime) / 1000
    if(difference > 3)
      alert('cerro la pagina')
    else 
      alert('recargo')
  }
}

window.unload = function(){
  var date = new Date();
  var milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds();
  localStorage.setItem('lastTime', milliseconds);
}
```